# Problem in comparing strings without assigning to variable

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

```
int i = ("aac" > "aab");
cout << i;
```

The above code does not give me the output as 1 (as it should be). But when I assign "aac" and "aab" to two separate string variables and use the variables instead of using strings directly (code attached below), I get the desired output.

Could anyone help me please?

```
string s1 = "aac";
string s2 = "aab";
int i = (s1 > s2);
cout << i;
```

Comment: `("aac">"aab");` compares two pointers to two distinct string literals; not two strings lexicographically. Consider yourself fortunate, it could have given you the answer you were expecting, but for an entirely different reason than you think.

Answer (score 2):

Literal constants like `"aac"` aren't `std::string` objects; rather, they are just data in (read-only) memory that evaluate, in most 'access' cases, to the address of their first element (i.e. a `char*` pointer); so, a comparison between them will be a comparison between those addresses — something you are unlikely to be able to control or predict.

To get an *inline* comparison, in your case, you can use *inline* `std::string` constructors (sometimes knows as "wrappers"), like this:

```cpp
    int i=(string("aac")>string("aab"));
```

Or, using the more 'modern' "curly-brace" initializer syntax:

```cpp
    int i = (string{ "aac" } > string{ "aab" });
```

For more brevity, you can make use of the fact that `std::string` has versions of the `>` (and similar) operators that take a string literal as one of the arguments; thus, you need only 'wrap' one of the literals, and could reduce the above code to something like:

```cpp
    int i = (string{ "aac" } > "aab");
```

Comment: Note: you can do this with only one of the literals wrapped in a ctor. The standard library provides the necessary operators to handle it.

Comment: And you can also use the suffix version: `using std::string_litteral; int i = "aac"s > "aab"s;`

Comment: @Jarod42 That one's new to me.

Comment: See [basic_string::operator""s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).

Comment: @Jarod42 Aha! But it was the misspelling of `string_literal` that confused me (he said, lying completely). :-)

Comment: Too late to fix typo in comment... :-/

Answer (score 1):

If you use C-style `char *` / `char []` strings, you need to use [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) like:

```cpp
int i = strcmp("aac", "aab");
```

Otherwise, you are just comparing addresses of the first elements of both of strings.